# @WebFilter("springSecurityFilterChain") throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern>

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, illegalargumentexception, url-pattern

I have a problem with my filter. I have it defined this way:

```
@WebFilter("springSecurityFilterChain")
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {...}
```

And in my web-fragment.xml I have:

```
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The pattern should be valid but I keep getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> springSecurityFilterChain in filter mapping
```

I've also tried to changing the pattern with "/", "/security/*", "" both in the XML and in @WebFilter annotation but I keep getting this exception. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

This is the Spring Security config:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and().authorizeRequests().
        anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.antMatcher("/rest/login").securityContext().disable();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your `@WebFilter` annotation. If you don't specify anything in `@WebFilter` annotation, then by default it takes param as URL pattern, which is `springSecurityFilterChain` in your case.

So for your case, you can use either

```
@WebFilter("/*") 
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {...}
```

without specifying anything in your xml file, or below:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "abc") 
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {...}
```

and in your xml file, you can specify the URL pattern as follow:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>abc</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Is container able to scan and register your filter class??

Comment: I don't get any exception and it used to thrown one while adding the filter so I assume that it managed to register it.

Comment: No. Despite what I said before, the filter is not registering at all. The only filter I can see is the loggerFilter.